# Maintaining state for performance improvement

Tags: c#

I have a class which calculates some result based on the state of variables.

```
 class CalculateService
 {
      public int Num1;
      public int Num2;

      public void Num1Updated(int num1, Action<int> callback)
      {       

       var result = TimeConsumingFunction(Num1, Num2);
       callback(result;)

       } 

    public void Num2Updated(int num2, Action<int> callback)
    {        

      var result = TimeConsumingFunction(Num1, Num2);
      callback(result;)

    } 

 }
```

The consumer of this class is another class. This class listens to an external datasource. Upon every field change it requests the calculator to calculate a result.

```
    class SomeOtherClass
    {

       CalculateService serviceObj;

       void func()
      {
         ExternalData.Field1.Changed(x=>{serviceObj.Num1Updated(x, (res) => 
         {       
           UpdateUI(res);
         });

         ExternalData.Field2.Changed(x=>{serviceObj.Num2Updated(x, (res) => 
         {
           UpdateUI(res);
         });
       }
     }
```

The problem: If `Field1` and `Field2` change in a short span of time, calling `TimeConsumingFunction()` twice is wasteful. How can I resolve this issue?

Perhaps I can wait few milliseconds before calling `TimeConsumingFunction()`?

Note that the problem is simplified here. There are more than two fields

Comment: Use caching. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications

Comment: Cancellation is not possible

Answer (score 1):

An event approach doesn't seem to be the best strategy here. I'd opt for a scheduled calculation launched at a convenient interval with a timer.

Before actually launching the calculation you could always check if data has changed caching the values on the previous *tick*. If the data is the same, simply do nothing and wait for the next *tick* to come around.

- Advantages: you'll only call `TimeConsumingFucntion` when data has
  changed.
- Disadvantages: your UI won't be updated "real time", but
  depending on the interval, the user doesn't really have to notice the
  difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like values actually change with every call caching on the side of the `TimeConsumingFunction` is not practical as you'd have return incorrect results if using previous values.

So one solution would be to pull the data from UI rather than pushing it to UI. That way you'll have one place to throttle calls.

Something like:

```
   ExternalData.Field1.Changed( _ => ScheduleUpdate());

   bool calculationInProgress = false;
   bool updatePending = false;
   void ScheduleUpdate()
   {
       updatePending = true;
       if (calculationInProgress)
       {
          return;
       }

       calculationInProgress = true;
       updatePending = false;
       service.ComputeAll(num1, num2,
          () => 
          {
                calculationInProgress = false;
                UpdateUI();       
                if (updatePending)
                {
                   ScheduleUpdate();
                }
          });
   }
```